# What is the right way to handle login in NextJS 14?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a backend that provides a login route "auth/login". Upon logging in, I receive a JWT. This JWT contains, among other things, an expiration time and a "userType" e.g., "admin". Now, I want to create a frontend dashboard with NextJS 14, which redirects the user to different dashboard areas depending on the "userType".

What I have done so far:

I have set up a login.tsx as a client component, which receives a JWT token from the backend using fetch. I store this JWT token in the browser with the "js-cookie" package. And this is where I'm stuck, because I'm wondering, firstly, is this the right approach? Should I perhaps use a server component for this case? Do I then read the token in a "middleware" and redirect the user to his/her area depending on the "userType"? Or is there only one area and I then display components in the dashboard depending on the "userType"?

For me, NextJS 14 is currently a black hole, and maybe someone here can tell me the best way to do this and why!

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Store the token in the cookies using `cookies-next` since it's support server side and having a middleware which validate the token on every interaction and based on that you would validate the users, your approach is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that  [Next Auth](https://next-auth.js.org) with credentials provider and JWT policy is not an option..? Also I would recommend switch from `js-cookie` to [cookies-next](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies-next). I made same transition and it was worth it, because `cookies-next` can be used client and server side.

Middleware approach would be better imo (checks made on server), same for going to server side with login page. Client should be used only if it's necessary (for example Context). And for redirections you can even go for custom url, like e.g. `/api/post-login.ts` - you can make [redirection](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#redirects) from there, if token was saved in cookies at client side:

```js
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
 
export async function GET(request: Request) {
  const cookieStore = cookies();
  const token = cookieStore.get('token');
  const { userType } = //decode your token here

  if(userType === "admin"){
   redirect('/admin/page')
   return;
  }

  if(userType === "normal"){
   redirect('/normal/page')
   return;
  }
}
```

And ofc that you can navigate user from client side after login (if you really need client there), by using [useRouter](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/redirect#client-component). New versions of next got plenty of options and server side is more and more important there.